# Remove all rows with dates containing specific hour:minute

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate, grepl

I have a dataframe with a column containing dates with `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M` format and would like to remove all rows with dates containing the time `12:00` regardless of month, day, and year. For a dataframe called `df` with a date column called `date` I tried running the following code but it didn't work:

`df <- df %>% filter(!grepl("12:00", date))`

Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make it clearer in the example below, I pasted **tstamp** as a character string, then parsed it. (These data are actually minutes on the shot clock, but we can ignore that for this example and pretend they're hours and minutes).

Then you use `hour(...) == 12` to extract and filter by hour, and `minute(...) == 0` to extract and filter by minute.

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

lakers %>%   
  select(date, time, opponent, team, player) %>% 
  mutate(tstamp = paste(date, time),
         tstamp.parsed = ymd_hm(tstamp)) %>% 
  filter(hour(tstamp.parsed) == 12, minute(tstamp.parsed) == 0) %>% 
  head
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 7
>       date  time opponent  team player         tstamp       tstamp.parsed
>      <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>          <chr>              <dttm>
> 1 20081028 12:00      POR   OFF        20081028 12:00 2008-10-28 12:00:00
> 2 20081029 12:00      LAC   OFF        20081029 12:00 2008-10-29 12:00:00
> 3 20081101 12:00      DEN   OFF        20081101 12:00 2008-11-01 12:00:00
> 4 20081105 12:00      LAC   OFF        20081105 12:00 2008-11-05 12:00:00
> 5 20081109 12:00      HOU   OFF        20081109 12:00 2008-11-09 12:00:00
> 6 20081111 12:00      DAL   OFF        20081111 12:00 2008-11-11 12:00:00
> ```